# Unable to create object error in dotnet ef migrations for MySql DbContext, but works for Sqlite DbContext

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have created 2 DbContexts for a new ASP.Net Core app.

https://github.com/jonasarcangel/IdentityMigrationsForMySql/tree/master/IdentityMigrationsForMySql/Server/Data

They are both derived from the same ApplicationDbContext base class, with the only difference being the OnConfiguring override, where UseMySql is used instead of UseSqlite, following what is suggested in this [post about multiple providers](https://logu.co/efcore-multiple-providers.html).

SqliteDbContext.cs has this:

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
#if DEBUG_EF
            options.UseSqlite("DataSource=");
#endif
        }
```

MySqlDbContext.cs has this:

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
#if DEBUG_EF
            options.UseMySql("Server=");
#endif
        }
```

The following command was run:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context MySqlDbContext --output-dir Migrations/MySql --configuration DebugEf
```

Error returned is:

> Unable to create an object of type 'MySqlDbContext'. For the different
> patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

However, the following command, which uses the context for Sqlite, is successful.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context SqliteDbContext --output-dir Migrations/Sqlite --configuration DebugEf
```

Comment: Please don't link to an external repository for the main code belonging to the question. If the link breaks, the question should still be comprehensible.

Comment: That's not nearly enough code for the question to survive a break in the link or (more likely) drastic changes in the linked code.

Comment: The repository was made specifically for this question. It's not the actual project that I need to fix.

Comment: Still, the question, all Stack Overflow questions, should be stand-alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in your `ConfigureServices` method, you're explicitly configuring a SqliteDbContext:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<SqliteDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            ...
        }
```

This creates migrations successfully if you change your code to `AddDbContext<MySqlDbContext>`, but then it would break the Sqlite build.

If you continue reading the article you linked, they describe how to fix this problem:

> In your application, you should continue to use `MyDb`. However, for
> EF to determine which migration to use, you have to call
> `services.GetService<T>` where T is one of the subclasses (instead of
> `MyDb`).
>
> Therefore, in `Startup.ConfigureServices`, register the subclasses:
>
> ```
> // Configure database 
> switch (config.DbProvider.ToLower()) {
> case "sqlite": {
>     services.AddDbContext<MyDb>(options => { options.UseSqlite(config.DbConnString); });
>     services.AddDbContext<SqliteMyDb>(options => { options.UseSqlite(config.DbConnString); });
> }
>     break;
> case "postgres": {
>     services.AddDbContext<MyDb>(options => options.UseNpgsql(config.DbConnString));
>     services.AddDbContext<NpgsqlMyDb>(options => options.UseNpgsql(config.DbConnString));
> }
>     break;
> default: {
>     throw new Exception($"DbProvider not recognized: {config.DbProvider}");
> } }
> ```
>
> Then, in Startup.Configure, do the migrations:
>
> ```
> void ProcessDb<T>()
> where T : MyDb {
>     using var db = services.GetService<T>();
>     db.Database.Migrate();
>
>     // ... perform other startup tasks with db }
>
> switch (config.DbProvider.ToLower()) {
>     case "sqlite": {
>         ProcessDb<SqliteMyDb>();
>         break;
>     }
>     case "postgres": {
>         ProcessDb<NpgsqlMyDb>();
>         break;
>     }
>     default: {
>         throw new Exception();
>     } }
> ```
>
> In summary, for each extra provider, add one subclass, a two-line case
> in ConfigureServices, and a case in Configure.

Comment: I didn't know that Startup.ConfigureServices is also called for "dotnet ef migrations".